# Horror movie about a demon (or telekinetic ?) boy who kills his family members

Tags: horror, story-identification, movie

There was a film I saw a few scenes of sometime during the early to mid 90s. 
I just remember a short scene but I think the scene is unique enough for someone to be able to identify it.

It had a small boy (I think he was in class or something, but he was with other adults; I think they were a man and a woman but I'm not sure). He had a hand drawn crayon picture of his family (I think; it might have been a foster family), a man, woman, a girl and a boy, and he had crossed out the woman in the picture with red (I think) crayon, which the adults around him notice as well.

In the next scene we see the woman in the kitchen, and and from a camera angle as if we are seeing her from the point of view of a dog (is there a name for this angle?). She looks at the camera, acts spooked and starts walking backwards. Throughout this scene she has a terrified look on her face, as if she is looking at a monster on the floor or something, who is slowly walking towards her. Then she screams and falls backwards on a pipe protruding out of the wall. It's implied that the pipe went through her skull and out her mouth, because in the next scene we see water coming out her of mouth, which soon turns from clear to a dark red.

This scene scared the hell out of me at the time so I am sure I didn't just imagine it. What movie was this?

Edit:

I remember seeing the film in English and most likely it was American

Comment: Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Comment: What colour hair did the woman have?. I've seen this scene. I can't place it though. Yet

Comment: @Darren: sorry can't remember. Probably blond or brown, and I think it was shoulder length. She was wearing a checkered (or similar type of colourful) shirt, but I really can't be sure about any of those details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [**Children of the Corn III: Urban Harvest**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109415/) from 1995.

> Two brothers connected to the murderous children's cult of Gatlin, Nebraska are taken to Chicago by an adoptive couple.

One of the brothers is evil and kills people supernaturally. And you can see the scene the details - the kid drawing, the low angle and the woman spooked by it (it's a vine that comes after her), her falling on a pipe and the water coming out of her mouth, it's all there.

*[BTW, this was Charlize Theron's first movie (they all have to start somewhere, I guess). And BTW II, this scene was possibly inspired by [a very similar death](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkeeYJSGS8Y) in 'My Bloody Valentine' from 1981 (WARNING: GORIER THIS TIME).]*

Comment: That's it !! I can't believe you found it! This scene's been stuck in my head for years and it was really annoying not being able to figure out where it's from. The kid doesn't look familiar but the drawing does, and for some reason I can't remember the vines or the garden setting (still got the image of a kitchen in my head), but the pipe scene is spot on.